# Is there a way to get ranger to syntax-highlight files using the X colorscheme of the terminal?

Tags: ranger

The file manager `ranger` works great, and uses the normal X resources color scheme of my terminal (urxvt). But when it shows a preview of files and highlights their syntax (presumably using `highlight` or `pygmentize`), the colors are all wrong, and look like default colors (bright blue, bright red, etc.). How can I get syntax highlighting in ranger to use the normal X colors? Running `cat some-file.py | pygmentize` seems to work fine and use my color scheme, but it doesn't seem to work in Ranger.

Comment: what do you have the colorscheme set to, for instance in rc.conf `set colorscheme default` is it set to default?  have you tried the other colorschemes that it ships with?

Answer (score 6):

Change

```
highlight_format=xterm256
```

to

```
highlight_format=ansi
```

in your `scope.sh` and reload.

Comment: This, saved me. I've added your answer to the Github issue as well, which did not have the fix you mentioned clearly.
https://github.com/ranger/ranger/issues/547#issuecomment-416172910

Answer (score 1):

Okay! After the previous response ended up not working for me, I did some experiments of my own and found that another part of `~/.config/ranger/scope.sh` has to be edited:

```
pygmentize_format='terminal256'
```

This has to be changed to:

```
pygmentize_format='terminal'
```

That coupled with changing `highlight_format='xterm256'` to `highlight_format='ansi'` as per the original solution should fix the problem!